# AES Encrypting in Obj-C and decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, objective-c, encryption, aes

I am fairly new to this. My PHP echo is returning garbage. I think there's an encoding step I'm missing.

My OBJ-C code

```
NSString *key = @"12345678901234561234567890123456";

    //main path for account login PHP file
    NSString *accountURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:configManager.accountURL, username, password];

    //convert password to data and encrypt
    NSData *crypt = [[[password stringValue]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]AES256EncryptWithKey:key];

    NSString *variables = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?username=%@&access=%@&page=%ld",[username stringValue], crypt, [sender tag]];

    // get rid of spaces in encoded URL
    NSString *niceURLString = [variables stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //tack niceURL on to end of base URL
    NSString *goToURL = [accountURL stringByAppendingString:niceURLString];
    NSLog(@"%@", goToURL);

    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:goToURL]];
```

PHP

```
$upswd = $_GET['access'];
    $key = "12345678901234561234567890123456";
$upswd = trim($upswd, "<>"); //remove these brackets from url

$result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $upswd, 'ecb');
//$result = utf8_decode($result);
echo ($result);
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you're using AES in ECB mode, which has very serious issues. You'd likely be much better off using any other mode (like CBC)- assuming the code on the iOS side is capable of any other mode (hopefully!).

Comment: I am in cocoa. Thanks for the tips. I will check.

Comment: I'm really lost with this. This is what I have now. `$key = "12345678901234561234567890123456";
$upswd = trim($upswd, "<>"); //remove these brackets from url

$result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, utf8_decode($upswd), 'ecb');
$result = utf8_decode($result);
echo ($result);` I just want to get it working in ECB then I'll switch once I know what I'm doing. I'm wondering if it's my obj-c code that's  messing it up. It needs to be decoded in utf-8 right?

Comment: You don't need to encode or decode an encrypted string with utf, it will either be in hex or binary format where char encoding is not needed. Now when passing the encrypted data to and from the encryption routines you want to make sure any encoding done is mirrored in reverse.

Comment: I'm trying everything here. I thought that this would work but it doesn't `$result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $upswd, 'ecb');`I'm wondering if there's a step missing from my obj-c code. See I'm passing it to a url... Should I be converting the NSdata to a string?

Comment: Why are you trying to roll your own crypto here? Running the PHP site under SSL will be far more secure, and much easier to set up and verify.

Comment: Basically, I need to send the user's pword via GET from cocoa to the browser's address bar. The receiving PHP logs the user in. Since it's via GET I need the pword to be relatively "encrypted". The security isn't a huge issue. If someone cracks a user's pword then there isn't really any info at stake - just access to some audio content. But I want at least some frontline of deterrence. I guess there's a better way to do it, but I don't yet have the know-how. This seemed the simplest in theory - encrypt with a key, decrypt with a key - but in practice it's proving more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        mcrypt_create_iv(
            mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
            )
```

You are creating an new IV, you need to use the original IV. It is usually passed along with the encrypted text seperated by a delimiter commonly used delimiters are . or | you then have PHP split the encrypted string at the delimiter, use the IV for the decrypt function and use the other part as the encrypted data.

Comment: Hmmm.. I just see one big block, but nothing that is an obvious delimiter. `486053a5%2016d83b3a%204ee09823%20b61b570b`